# Handle Json Response

Tags: php, json

I have to show Json Response for each my route, even if I get an error.

For example, I have this class

```
class File {
  private $fileName;


  public function parseFile($file){
    $value = Yaml::parse(file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../../'.$file));
    return $value;
  }
  public function getFileName() {
    return $this->fileName;
  }
  public function setFileName($fileName) {
    $this->fileName = $fileName;
  }

}
```

my controller is:

```
$file = new File();
$file->setFileName('conf/conf.yml');
$value = $file->parseFile($file->getFileName());
//return response if $value is empty
//run this code only if value isn't empty
```

How can I show a response with a custom Json like:

```
{
error:10,
msg: ‘foo’
}
```

I have to check anytime the type of $value ? For example

```
if(empty($value))
```

And How can I handle if another class call parseFile instead of controller?

How can I show the Json in this case?

Comment: need some context...  you're obviously working within a framework?  What's the framework?

Comment: @BradKent in this case Slim Framework, I have to use Event ? and if I use a "simple" Php ?

Comment: off topic: `dirname(__FILE__)` can be replaced with `__DIR__`

Answer (score 0):

Encode the value

```
  <?php 
       if(strlen($value)){
            $value = json_encode($value); 
       }else{
            $value = json_encode(["error"=>10,"msg"=>'foo']);
       }
  ?>
```

Comment: yes, maybe my english is not so good to explain my doubt. I want to now if I have to check anytime the type of $value to know if I have to do json_encode($value) or not. because I need to stop the excetution if $value is empty for example

Comment: Without an `if()` statement... `$value = json_encode($value ?: ["error"=>10,"msg"=>'foo']);`